# Backward compatibility for the Caches directory

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, directory, backwards-compatibility, icloud

One of the iCloud recommendations is to use the `Library/Caches` directory to store files that don't need to be backed up to the cloud. What is the backward compatibility for this directory like? Do I need to create it if it doesn't exist on iPhone OS 3.0? Can I depend on it being there and use code like this to get its path?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachesDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSCachesDirectory was introduced in iOS 2.0.